# White edges appearing at edge of cube

Tags: iphone, android, opengl-es, webgl

When I render a cube and texture it I end up with white edges along the cube.  I've checked the vertex and texture coordinates and they look fine to me.  My texture is a power of 2.  It is a texture map containing 4x4 textures in which each texture is 16x16 pixels.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: give us some code how you call it

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are experiencing texture bleeding. You can solve it by either using GL_CLAMP on your textures or adjusting slightly your UV coordinates to 0.0005 and 0.0095 (for instance) instead of 0 and 1 to compensate for the texture sampling artifacts.